# How to search for a specific byte in all files in a directory?

Tags: linux, grep

I have a bunch of files in mixed encodings of utf8 and ISO8859-1. The only real difference between them is 4 characters which I want to convert to utf8. I'll do that manually, all I need is to find the files they occur in.

I tried grepping for them with `grep -rlP '[\xe4\xf5\xf6\xfc\xc4\xd6\xd5\xdc]' *` but didn't realize that the byte codes for those characters in ISO8859-1 are the exact same as the Unicode code point values for the same characters in Unicode (even though in UTF8 they are represented in 2 bytes).

I couldn't figure out how to make `grep` look for byte values instead of code points... so here I am. PS! I cannot install anything on the given CentOS 7 computer.

How do I search for a specific byte or variety of bytes in all files within a directory?

Comment: How would you (or `grep` for that matter) differentiate between them? I guess you'll need to check if the file is a binary first before running `grep` on it

Comment: `LC_ALL=C grep -rlP '[\xe4...]' ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do that by running `grep` under the C locale.

The string `ööli` is the seven bytes `c3 b6 c3 b6 6c 69 0a` in UTF-8, and `ö` is U+00F6.

Assuming you're in an UTF-8 locale, `grep -P` would look for the character U+00F6:

```
$ echo 'ööli' |grep -o -P '\xf6'
ö
ö
```

And in the C locale, this would look for the byte C3:

```
$ echo 'ööli' |LC_ALL=C grep -o -P '\xc3'| od -tx1
0000000 c3 0a c3 0a
```